# Regex replace with multiple wildcards works in PHP, not in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, regex

I'm attempting to implement center alignment for two Markdown parsers:

1. In **PHP** for [Parsedown](http://parsedown.org/) (successfully)
2. In **JavaScript** for [Bootstrap Markdown](http://toopay.github.io/bootstrap-markdown/) (without success)

The idea I'm following and finding the easiest is to work with the final HTML output, and just snap inline styling onto the tags.

The following regex does what I need, it adds `style="text-align:center;"` to *any* element so far*, as needed:

```
$text = preg_replace('/\<(.*?)\>\-&gt;(.*?)&lt;\-\<\/(.*?)\>/', '<$1 style="text-align:center;">$2</$3>', $text);
```

That is, `<p>text</p>` becomes `<p style="text-align:center;">text</p>`.

However, when I attempted to port this into JavaScript to also make it available for previewing on client-side, the pattern does not match as it should:

```
content = content.replace('/\<(.*?)\>\-&gt;(.*?)&lt;\-\<\/(.*?)\>/', '<$1 style="text-align:center;">$2</$3>');
```

The replacement in `content` does not occur.

I'm aware there are slight differences between Regex of PHP and JavaScript, but I have found examples for all the expected behavior here on both sides, working.

---

*If someone is wondering by any chance, I'm also successfully adding the center alignment to tags that already have a style attribute - on server side only, so far.

Comment: I ran into this a while back. If I remember right js does not like quotes around regex.

Comment: `JavaScript != PHP`, read up on the methods you're using on MDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the literal syntax for regular expression in JavaScript, like so:

```
content = content.replace(/\<(.*?)\>\-&gt;(.+)&lt;\-\<\/(.+)\>/gi, '<$1 style="text-align:center;">$2</$3>');
```

Note that the `gi` at the end of the regular expression simply enables global searching (that is, replace all occurrences matching the pattern) and case-insensitive matching. They are both technically optional, but you will most likely want the `g` flag enabled for certain. However,  keeping the `i` flag is up to you (depends on whether or not your content contains `&GT;`, for example).

Comment: have you tested the code? it doesn't work on my console

Comment: It works here so far, give me a brief minute, please. :) If I understand right, Regex in JS `String.replace()` "does not work" if passed as a string, right?

Comment: Well, the String `replace()` method technically does accept patterns formatted as strings. However, such patterns are not treated as regular expressions, and only the first matching instance is replaced. My advice: always use regular expression literals for the `replace()` method in JS.